# Как построить блоки .shop__body как на этом сайте?

Tags: html, css, grid

Хочу сделать аналог макета как на скриншоте.
Прошу прощения, если не смог в БЭМ (только постигаю эту методологию).
[image: Постарался указать по модификатору, чтобы было понятно где и какой виджет должен быть]
Решил сделать виджеты, которые сделаны в селекторе .shop на гридах, используя grid-template-areas, но пока затрудняюсь с реализацией.
Как можно реализовать эту идею не используя большое количество селекторов в классах или в стилизации?
Пока текущая версия моих попыток написана тут:

```css
.shop__widgets {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 16.66667vw);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 16.66667vw);
  grid-template-areas: "sm sm col col wide wide" "wide wide col col sm sm";
}

.shop__widgets :nth-child(n) {
  background: greenyellow;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.shop .widget_sm {
  grid-area: sm;
}

.shop .widget_col {
  grid-area: col;
  grid-row: 1 / 8;
}

.shop .widget_wide {
  grid-area: wide;
}
```

```html
<section class="shop">
  <div class="shop__widgets">
    <div class="widget_sm saddle1">widget_sm</div>
    <div class="widget_sm saddles">widget_sm</div>
    <div class="widget_col back-bag">widget_col</div>
    <div class="widget_col bike">widget_col</div>
    <div class="widget_wide gallery">widget_wide</div>
    <div class="widget_wide saddle2">widget_wide</div>
    <div class="widget_sm saddle3">widget_sm</div>
    <div class="widget_sm bag">widget_sm</div>
  </div>
  <div class="shop__btn-block"></div>
</section>
```

Upd1. Сделал решение левой половины блока виджетов. Прошу прощения за то, что поменялись селекторы отчасти или полностью, но мне кажется, что для реализации идеи можно найти более элегантное решение, поэтому хотелось бы узнать мнение любого, кто захочет уделить свое время на этот вопрос

```css
div {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.table {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
}
.table__left {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
.table__right {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}

.shop__block .widget {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat 3, 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat 2, 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  grid-template-areas: "sm1 sm2 col" "wide wide col";
}
.shop__block .widget .saddle1 {
  grid-area: sm1;
  background: yellow;
}
.shop__block .widget .saddles {
  grid-area: sm2;
  background: #3ae6ca;
}
.shop__block .widget_col {
  grid-area: col;
  background: green;
}
.shop__block .widget_wide {
  grid-area: wide;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<section class="shop">
  <div class="shop__block table">
    <div class="table__left widget">
      <div class="widget_sm saddle1">widget_sm1</div>
      <div class="widget_sm saddles">widget_sm2</div>
      <div class="widget_wide saddle2">widget_wide</div>
      <div class="widget_col back-bag">widget_col</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table__right">
      <div class="widget_col bike">widget_col</div>
      <div class="widget_wide gallery">widget_wide</div>
      <div class="widget_sm saddle3">widget_sm</div>
      <div class="widget_sm bag">widget_sm</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shop__btn-block"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Приложите скриншоты и опишите подробно образец, ибо никто по "левым" ссылкам не хочет ходить, а в вопросе мало информации.

Comment: @UModeL Прошу прощения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, не очень понимаю, зачем в этом примере необходима разметка с помощью grid-template-areas. Тут достаточно простая сетка 6x2 и можно задать span-ы плиточкам:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  gap: 4px;
}

.item {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 1em;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}

.item.col {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
  aspect-ratio: initial;
}

.item.wide {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  aspect-ratio: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item col">3</div>
  <div class="item col">4</div>
  <div class="item wide">5</div>
  <div class="item wide">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

**UPD:** Добавил адаптивный вариант с демонстрацией принципа работы `grid-template-areas` (можно увидеть, развернув снипет на полный экран и уменьшив окно до 500px)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b c d e e"
    "f f c d g h";
  gap: 4px;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: c;
}
.item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: d
}
.item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: e
}
.item:nth-child(6) {
  grid-area: f
}

.item {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 1em;
}
.item:first-child,
.item:last-child {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: 
      "a b"
      "e e"
      "c d"
      "c d"
      "f f"
      "g h"
  }
  
  .item {
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  }
  .item:nth-child(3), 
  .item:nth-child(4) {
     aspect-ratio: 1/2;
  }
  .item:nth-child(5), 
  .item:nth-child(6) {
     aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: я хотел с помощью areas предусмотреть смещение необходимых мне блоков указывая необходимые медиа-запросы.
Таким образом, я думал, что если пользователь зайдет на страницу с мобильного устройства areas будет двухколоночным и иметь вид:
"sm sm"
"wide (на две колонки)"
"col col"
"wide(на две колонки)"
"sm sm"

Comment: @ПавелПетров Отредактировал, как вы хотели

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что в случае использования grid-template-area требуется иметь уникальные идентификаторы для каждого блока элементов?

Comment: @ПавелПетров чтобы не запутать вас, дам самую очевидную ссылку на примеры: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas